# Regular Expressions in Log Parser Lizard

Tags: regex, parsing, multiline

I've got some custom logfiles that I'm trying to parse using the regex engine in Log Parser Lizard. I feel like I should be able to parse them, but I can't get it to work at all. The log file is structured like this:

```
2016-09-20 00:42:29.420 DBG    8 Finished receiving 154 bytes from 100.100.100.100:6000.[cr][lf]
2016-09-20 00:42:29.420 DBG    8 The document received is:[lf]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><tagname:stuff xmlns:data="some:data:here">[lf]
  <more:stuff xmlns:blah="more:stuff">[lf]
  </more:stuff>[lf]
</tagname:stuff>[lf]
[cr][lf]
2016-09-20 00:42:29.420 DBG    8 Parsing the document for information...[cr][lf]
2016-09-20 00:42:29.420 INF    8 Finished parsing incoming document for stuff from 100.100.100.100:6000.[cr][lf]
```

([cr] and [lf] above are representations of encoded carriage returns/line feeds, and not literal characters.)

The idea here is that each record ends with carriage return/line feed. However, the second message field in the second record is multi-line, ending with line feeds only. (No carriage return.) I need that multiline field to be contained in its entirety, which **should** be possible using regex.

In several regex testers, I have this line seemingly working as intended:

```
(?<DateTime>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3})\s*(?<Type>\w+?)\s*(?<Thread>\d+?)\s*(?m:(?<Message>(?:.*\n?)*))
```

If I plug this into [RegExBuddy](https://www.regexbuddy.com/), and if I set it to PCRE and set line breaks to "CR, LF or CRLF" then it works flawlessly. However, when I enter it into the regexfileconfig.xml in LPL, (properly escaped, of course) the message for line two is "The document received is:" and nothing else. It ignores the whole of the XML document. (Which absolutely needs to be parsed for this tool to be of any value to me.)

I've tried using RegExBuddy to convert it to C#(.NET 2.0-4.6) format, and it spits out this regex:

```
(?<DateTime>[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}[\t\n\v\f\r ][0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3})[\t\n\v\f\r ]*(?<Type>[0-9A-Za-z_]+?)[\t\n\v\f\r ]*(?<Thread>[0-9]+?)[\t\n\v\f\r ]*(?m:(?<Message>(?:[^\n\r]*\n?)*))
```

With all other options set at the default, again, it works perfectly. However, it does not work at all in Log Parser Lizard. I have tried setting the query type to all 4 different types of RegEx, but each of them produces a different result, none of them correct.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

**EDIT** Expected Output:
Log Parser Lizard returns the data as a table, with the named capture groups as column headers. I'm looking for a table like this:

```
DateTime                 Type   Thread   Message
2016-09-20 00:42:29.420  DBG    8        Finished receiving 154 bytes from 100.100.100.100:6000.    
2016-09-20 00:42:29.420  DBG    8        The document received is:
                                         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><tagname:stuff xmlns:data="some:data:here">
                                           <more:stuff xmlns:blah="more:stuff">
                                           </more:stuff>
                                         </tagname:stuff>
2016-09-20 00:42:29.420  DBG    8        Parsing the document for information...
2016-09-20 00:42:29.420  INF    8        Finished parsing incoming document for stuff from 100.100.100.100:6000.
```

Comment: I've never worked with Log Parser Lizard, but I suggest you to try passing multi-line flag (m) with regex text. I don't know exactly how you can do that.

Comment: What regex flavor does that tool suppott?

Comment: RegEx Buddy supports _all_ of the regex flavors. Allegedly, Log Parser Lizard uses the C# .NET library, but so far, I can't get that working.

Comment: May I ask you update your question with expected output? It's hard for me to look at that regex and get it.

Comment: I think your regex is correct.  You need to ensure that Log Parser Lizard is not treating the `\n` as an end-of-record.  I don't know LPL, so I don't know how you do this, but you need to ensure that LPL is only looking at `\r\n` as an end-of-record marker.